# ACTION_CALL intent with a specific dialer

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that opens the voice channel through ACTION_CALL. At this moment, it works great but there's the case in which the user has more than one dialer.

This application is about fall detection so the user has no time (it is life or death matter) to choose among the multiple dialer he has then I want to put it as a configuration or even make the call using the system default dialer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to avoid the chooser you should set the component name:

```
// i.e. Applications.getIntentForActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND), "Messaging");
public static Intent getIntentForActivity(Intent intent, String hint) {
    ResolveInfo info = getActivityForIntent(intent, hint);
    if (info == null)
        return intent;
    ComponentName name = Applications.getComponentForActivity(info);
    if (name == null)
        return intent;
    // intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    // | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    intent.setComponent(name);
    return intent;
}
```